SQL Server fails to start on Ubuntu 22.04
I created a new instance of Azure VM running Ubuntu 22.04 just to reproduce this issue.
I'm following this guide to install the SQL server on my freshly deployed VM. There should be definitely enough resources to run it with 8GB RAM and 2 CPU cores.
I did run sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade before proceeding.
After running sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup I go through the SQL server setup journey, setting the sa password. It warns me about a missing the library.
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
Configuring SQL Server...

/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mssql-server.service → /lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.
Setup has completed successfully. SQL Server is now starting.

When I try to verify that the service is running using systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager I get the following output:
sebastian@seb-linux-azure:~$ systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-04-18 09:03:08 UTC; 14s ago
       Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
    Process: 8875 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 8875 (code=exited, status=127)

Apr 18 09:03:08 seb-linux-azure systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Apr 18 09:03:08 seb-linux-azure systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Apr 18 09:03:08 seb-linux-azure systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 18 09:03:08 seb-linux-azure systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 18 09:03:08 seb-linux-azure systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

Is this something very recent that Microsoft hasn't updated in their docs or am I missing something? It certainly wasn't an issue when I tried to do the same on IBM virtual machines about a week ago.
Let me know if further details are required and which command I need to get them, as I'm fairly new to Linux.

The missing library should be provided by libldap-2.5-0, I suggest you install the package and run the setup again before debugging anything else.
